# wget not able to log into ftp

Tags: wget, proxy

I am trying to use wget for downloading files from a ftp repository. The FTP repository has a login and password. I have to go through a proxy server which does not have a login and password. When I try to use the normal,

`wget -r -c ftp://login:pass@download.site.co.in/`

I find that it tries to login to the proxy server itself rather than the ftp server causing it to hang at that stage. using `--ftp-user` and `ftp-password` has the same effect. How can I get around this?

Comment: This question might be better placed on superuser.com

Comment: is the proxy configured in the system?

Comment: It is configured via environment variable ftp_proxy

Comment: Silly question: is your proxy server also an FTP proxy server? An HTTP proxy server uses the "Host:" line to figure out what page to grab. An FTP proxy server would have to be more clever (ie, know the IP address it's intercepting).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think wget supports the username and password in a URL.  Try this form:

```
wget --user=login --password=pass ftp://download.site.co.in/
```

Better yet, you can store the username and password in .wgetrc or .netrc to prevent having to specify it on the command-line where it might be seen by other users or stored to a shell history file.  I'm not sure about the format of .wgetrc, you can read the man page on wget for that.  For .netrc, add a line like:

```
machine download.site.co.in login login pasword pass
```

And wget will automatically use that if not specified.  Make sure the file is chmod 700 for permissions.